# Changing .json file in python

Tags: python, json, pandas

**I have the following .json file like this:**

```
[
  {
    "2004": "0",
    "2005": "0",
    "2006": "0",
    
  },
  {
    "2004": "0",
    "2005": "0",
    "2006": "0",
  },
  {
  
    "2013": "0",
    "2014": "0",
    "2015": "--",
  }
]
```

**How to do in python to get a following .json file like this:**

```
{
 "Countries": [
   {
    "2004": "0",
    "2005": "0",
    "2006": "0"
   },
   {
    "2004": "0",
    "2005": "0",
    "2006": "0"
   },
   {
    "2013": "0",
    "2014": "0",
    "2015": "--"
   }
 ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your case of using files change to `use_files = True` in the beginning of script and set correct files names instead of `'input.json'` and `'output.json'`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tVJNa4QwEL3nVwy5REFFu9tShJ4K/ROliF0n3SyaSD6wZdnfbhO1si1SemkOSebNzJuZl/Qf9qjkbhxF1ytt4WSUJMQZrLho0cADPNWtQSJkX3FZd5iAcna@eifzuLNZyGIJMO9aTUIEB6ksrGQlAb8svlufSSmdzOdpBzgvJwC9yfM9LYHmNPkG3m6BdzO4YJfkf@muY4vdBkGxVaqYSqXpSjudL9MedAhK/VBpEPYIqkcZXSnPtBcZ5UE1Qr4F9Z3l6T2LoTbAy7XiojDPNNZNFBOiXk/eDq@StapuTBQi4gU@s0flpNUCDSvBYxeiF4Ypo3FdbyKPJyBkgzI49qEN4zRWtTkI8fVL4rWFXydaP5CfaPjTRDwbtLAY6blx9LVmZ6@FtAs8jp8)

```
import json

use_files = False
inp_fname, out_fname = 'input.json', 'output.json'

if not use_files:
    text = """
    [
      {
        "2004": "0",
        "2005": "0",
        "2006": "0"
      },
      {
        "2004": "0",
        "2005": "0",
        "2006": "0"
      },
      {
      
        "2013": "0",
        "2014": "0",
        "2015": "--"
      }
    ]
    """

if use_files:
    with open(inp_fname, 'r', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
        text = f.read()

obj = json.loads(text)
obj = {'Countries': obj}
rtext = json.dumps(obj, indent = 4, ensure_ascii = False)
        
if use_files:
    with open(out_fname, 'w', encoding = 'utf-8') as f:
        f.write(rtext)
else:
    print(rtext)
```

the code outputs:

```
{
    "Countries": [
        {
            "2004": "0",
            "2005": "0",
            "2006": "0"
        },
        {
            "2004": "0",
            "2005": "0",
            "2006": "0"
        },
        {
            "2013": "0",
            "2014": "0",
            "2015": "--"
        }
    ]
}
```